# Groupby two columns one of them is datetime

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have data frame that I want to groupby by two columns one of them is datetime type. How can I do this?

```
import pandas as pd 
import datetime as dt 

df = pd.DataFrame({ 


'a':np.random.randn(6),
'b':np.random.choice( [5,7,np.nan], 6),
'g':{1002,300,1002,300,1002,300}
'c':np.random.choice( ['panda','python','shark'], 6),

# some ways to create systematic groups for indexing or groupby
# this is similar to r's expand.grid(), see note 2 below
'd':np.repeat( range(3), 2 ),
'e':np.tile(   range(2), 3 ),

# a date range and set of random dates
'f':pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=6, freq='D'),
'g':np.random.choice( pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=365, 
                      freq='D'), 6, replace=False) 
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) to specify groupby instructions. It can be used with `pd.DatetimeIndex` index to group data with specified frequency using the `freq` parameter.

Assumming that you have this dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    a=dict(date=pd.Timestamp('2020-05-01'), category='a', value=1),
    b=dict(date=pd.Timestamp('2020-06-01'), category='a', value=2),
    c=dict(date=pd.Timestamp('2020-06-01'), category='b', value=6),
    d=dict(date=pd.Timestamp('2020-07-01'), category='a', value=1),
    e=dict(date=pd.Timestamp('2020-07-27'), category='a', value=3),
)).T
```

You can set index to `date` column and it would be converted to `pd.DatetimeIndex`. Then you can use pd.Grouper among with another columns. For the following example I use `category` column.

`freq='M'` parameter used to group index using month frequency. There are number of [string data series aliases](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) that can be used in `pd.Grouper`

```py
df.set_index('date').groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='M'), 'category'])['value'].sum()
```

Result:

```
date        category
2020-05-31  a           1
2020-06-30  a           2
            b           6
2020-07-31  a           4
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Another example with your mcve:

```py
df.set_index('g').groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='M'), 'c']).d.sum()
```

Result:

```
g           c     
2011-01-31  panda     0
2011-04-30  shark     2
2011-06-30  panda     2
2011-07-31  panda     0
2011-09-30  panda     1
2011-12-31  python    1
Name: d, dtype: int32
```